# Opening a ContextMenu with an ImageButton

Tags: android

For some reason I can't create a context menu.

I have these lines in onCreate:

```
btnMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

registerForContextMenu(btnMenu);
```

And added the method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
}
```

I have an xml file in res/menu called mainmenu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:title="item1"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="item2" 
    />

</menu>
```

But when I click the imagebutton nothing appears.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you implements `View.OnCreateContextMenuListener` in your activity?

Comment: hmm nope, it wasn't mentioned in the guides

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried your code, and it worked great. Be careful, you need a long press on the view (in this example on the button), not a short click. If you want to show the context menu for a short click, try something like this:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

registerForContextMenu(b);

b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.showContextMenu();
}   
});
```